# Can I always use findNavController(mView) to find a NavController in Android Studio 3.5.2

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

The following sample code *CameraFragment.kt* and *activity_main.xml* is from [camera-samples](https://github.com/android/camera-samples/tree/master/CameraXBasic/app/src/main/java/com/android/example/cameraxbasic) project.

It find the NavController using `findNavController(requireActivity(), R.id.fragment_container)`.

I think it's a complex, can I always use `findNavController(mView)` to find the NavController ? just like Code A?

**CameraFragment.kt**

```
private fun updateCameraUi() {    
       ...          
       Navigation.findNavController(requireActivity(), R.id.fragment_container).navigate(
              CameraFragmentDirections.actionCameraToGallery(outputDirectory.absolutePath))

}
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<FrameLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:keepScreenOn="true"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
        android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:defaultNavHost="true"
        app:navGraph="@navigation/nav_graph" />

</FrameLayout>
```

**Code A**

```
private lateinit var mView: View 

override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
   super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
   mView=view
   ...
}


Navigation.findNavController(mView).navigate(
           CameraFragmentDirections.actionCameraToGallery(outputDirectory.absolutePath))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't even need to use `Navigation.findNavController(mView)` when in a Fragment - you can use `NavHostFragment.findNavController(this)` to find the `NavHostFragment` from a Fragment as per the [Navigate to a destination documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-navigate).

But yes, you can also use `Navigation.findNavController(mView)` or use any View from within the Fragment.

You'd only want to use `findNavController(requireActivity(), R.id.fragment_container)` when you only have the Activity. While it works, there easier ways to do the same thing.

Comment: Thank! Are you sure that I can use NavHostFragment.findNavController(this) to find  the NavController when in a Fragment?

Comment: Where `this` is your Fragment, yep. That's exactly what it is used for. Of course, if you're using Kotlin and the `navigation-fragment-ktx` artifact, then you can also just use [`findNavController()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/navigation/fragment/package-summary#(androidx.fragment.app.Fragment).findNavController())` Kotlin extension on `Fragment`. TBH, same for the other `findNavController` calls, which have similar extension methods (i.e., `mView.findNavController()`)